# Use 3 methods (Addition, numberEven, numberOdd) in Java with a static array

Tags: java

I have an array named `tab` with several numbers

```
int[] tab = {1,3,4,2};
```

I have to create 3 methods:

1) the first `addition()` method

2) the second `evenNumber()` method

3) the third `evenOdd()` method

I have 2 results to display below by using my 3 methods:

```
# 1 - Calculate the sum of all even numbers in the table 
# 2 - Calculate the sum of all odd numbers in the table
```

I found the way to retrieve all even numbers and then, I add up the even numbers , the result is `6`

Concerning the odd numbers the result should be `4` and I retrieve **0** ???

[image]

I don't understand my problem.

Here is an idea of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        int[] tab = {1,3,4,2};

        int length = tab.length;

        length = evenNumber(tab, length);
        int evenSum = addition(tab, length);


        length = oddNumber(tab, length);
        int oddSum = addition(tab, length);


        System.out.println("# 1 - Calculate the sum of all even numbers in the table -> " + evenSum);
        System.out.println("# 2 - Calculate the sum of all odd numbers in the table -> " + oddSum);



    }

    public static int addition(int tab[], int length){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            sum += tab[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int evenNumber(int tab[], int length){
        int n = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            if(tab[i] % 2 == 0){
                tab[n++] = tab[i];
            }
        }
        return n;

    }

   public static int oddNumber(int[] tab, int length) {
        int n=0;
        for(int i=0; i<length;i++){
            if(tab[i] % 2 == 1 ){ 
               tab[n++] = tab[i];
            }
        }
       return n;
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what is the use of method evenNumber() and oddNumber()

Comment: @TheGoldy: To retrieve the even numbers or odd numbers

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to look at the contents of `tab` after calling `evenNumber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work for you:
`addallNumbers()` does what it says, and `addEvenOrOddNumbers()` adds all even numbers if the `even` flag is set to `true`, or if it's set to `false` adds all odd numbers.

```
public class Main {
    // This adds all numbers.
    public static int addAllNumbers(int[] arr){
        int sum = 0;
        int length = arr.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
    // This adds all odd or even numbers, based on the value of even.
    public static int addEvenOrOddNumbers(int[] arr, boolean even){
        int parity = 0;
        if (!even){
            parity = 1;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        int length = arr.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
            if (arr[i] % 2 == parity) {
                sum += arr[i];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] tab = {1,3,4,2};

        System.out.println("Added all numbers, Result: " + addAllNumbers(tab));
        System.out.println("Added all even numbers, Result: " + addEvenOrOddNumbers(tab, true));
        System.out.println("Added all odd numbers, Result: " + addEvenOrOddNumbers(tab, false));
    }
}
```

When run this outputs:

```
Added all numbers, Result: 10
Added all even numbers, Result: 6
Added all odd numbers, Result: 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are dragging length and passing it to all the methods and returning it (why?). Also, I don't think you are doing what the name of your methods suggest.

What you want to do is something like this (I'm guessing this is homework):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        // Input array with all the numbers
        int[] tab = {1,3,4,2};

        // Calculate even and odd sums
        int[] sums = calculateSums(tab);

        // Extract results
        int evenSum = sums[0];
        int oddSum  = sums[1];

        // Print the results
        System.out.println("# 1 - Calculate the sum of all even numbers in the table -> " + evenSum);
        System.out.println("# 2 - Calculate the sum of all odd numbers in the table -> " + oddSum);
    }

    public static int[] calculateSums(int[] tab) {
        // Initialize even and odd sums to zero
        int[] sums = {0, 0};

        // Loop through the array to check the numbers one by one
        for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            int n = tab[i]; // n is the current number

            if (evenNumber(n)) {
                // Add to evenSum if it's even
                sums[0] += n;
            }

            if (oddNumber(n)) {
                // Add to oddSum if it's odd
                sums[1] += n;
            }
        }
        return sums;
    }

    // Receives an array of integers and returns the total sum
    public static int addition(int tab[]){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
            sum += tab[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    // Checks if a number is even
    public static boolean evenNumber(int number){
        return number % 2 == 0;

    }

    // Checks if a number is odd
    public static boolean oddNumber(int number) {
        return !evenNumber(number);
    }
```

If you run the program it will print:

```
# 1 - Calculate the sum of all even numbers in the table -> 6
# 2 - Calculate the sum of all odd numbers in the table -> 4
```

Methods required by you exercise:

- `addition()`: Takes an array of numbers and returns the total sum
- `evenNumber()`: Takes a number and returns true if the number is even
- `oddNumber()`: Takes a number and returns true if the number is odd

If you think about it, inside the `for` loop you don't even need to use both `evenNumber` and `oddNumber` because if a number is not even it must be odd and viceversa. A simple `if-else` would be enough, and this is also why I implemented one using the other (`oddNumber` calls `evenNumber`).

Try to do that and see if you still get the desired results. Please make sure you really understand what your code is doing, and ask here if I got something wrong with your requirements (I had to guess a bit).

I have commented the code way too much due to the learning nature of your question.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanations and your time. I have an ask please. Is it possible to put the loop `for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) { ...`  in a method ? Please

Comment: Yes plese... Is his a requirement. Thank you

Comment: There you go, I've updated the answer. Makes it look a bit weird in my opinion but result should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like that

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] tab = {1,3,4,2};
    System.out.println("Sum of even numbers = " + sumEvens(tab)); // return sum printed 
    System.out.println("Sum of odd numbers = " + sumOdds(tab));
    System.out.println("Total sum " + totalSum(tab));
}
public static int sumEvens(int[] tab) {
    int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < tab.length ; ++i) {
      if(tab[i] % 2 == 0) sum+=tab[i];
  }
     return sum;
}
public static int sumOdds(int[] tab) { // returns sum of odds
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < tab.length ; ++i) {
        if(tab[i] % 2 != 0) sum+=tab[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
public static int totalSum(int[] tab) { 
    return sumEvens(tab) + sumOdds(tab);// total sum is equal to sum of even and odd sums
}
```

}